# core data multithread using

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data

Dear community. 
When i has a stable version of my application, while i don't start change code to multithread version. What was a difference between previous version:
in (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
i do loop to add to queue my code:

```
 NSOperationQueue *opQueueImportUpdateFirstTimeData =   [[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init]autorelease];
 int i = 0;
 for (NSString *carrier in currentCarriers)
 {
    AppController *operation = [[AppController alloc] initAndUpdateCarrier:carrier identifier:i];
    [opQueueImportUpdateFirstTimeData addOperation:operation]; 
    i++;
 }
```

External class have:

```
- (id)initAndUpdateCarrier:(NSString *)forCarrier 
                identifier:(NSUInteger)iQuene;
{
    [super init];
    [self setIdentifierQuene:iQuene];
    [self setStartForCarrier:forCarrier];
    [self setPercentDone:0.0];
```

**This point is a very important:**

```
    [self setDatabase:[[MySQLIXC alloc] init]];
```

u can't alloc other classes in process of u multithreading, i don't know why, but this is take malloc_error in whole queues

```
    [self setAppDelegate:[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]];
    [self setManagedObjectContext:[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]];
    return self;
}
```

And in external class i have:

```
 -(void) main;
{

[self makeUpdatesForCarrier:startForCarrier andTypeOfOperation:@"rates" forDirection:@"incoming"];// mySqlConnector:database];
```

it's a just some functions which working on local moc.
When i start application, interface didn't place it in background, and start visualization only after all queues will finish.

Before i try to alloc]init] MySQLIXC class inside my external class, but it gives me a lot of malloc_error_break exceptions, like somebody try to freeze memory for me.
Tnx.

Here is moc declaration:
in .h:

```
@property(retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

in .m:
    @synthesize managedObjectContext;

Set persistent store coordinator:

```
[[self managedObjectContext] setUndoManager:nil];
[[self managedObjectContext] setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];
```

Merge changes for with main moc:

```
- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

// Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
[mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) 
                              withObject:notification
                           waitUntilDone:YES];
```

And in one place of my code i'm using a main moc (only for read information, i know that moc not thread safe):

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DestinationsListForSale"
                               inManagedObjectContext:mainContext]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastUsedProfit > 0"]; 
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, CoreData is NOT thread safe. I would strongly advise that if you do not understand core data in a good deal of detail you keep you application singlethreaded or at the very least ensure that you always access the store from a single thread (probably best to use the main thread).

That said, this will not cause malloc_error_breaks AFAIK. You would see core data merge error exceptions and similar problems.

Could you show the code where you set up the moc further - just allocating and initing a moc is not enough - you have to set it's NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

Comment: Dear Roger, question was update. Main issue, which i find, that i can't make instance of external classes in code, just in init. After i make changes, all malloc error was out. But probably u can suggest something more in this case, for example how i can keep some data like array between threads.

Comment: NSArray is kindof threadsafe so it should just work - the normal proviso applies that you will need to lock any shared access. Just because NSArry doesn't blow up doesn't mean your design is threadsafe. Unless you really need threading support, I would avoid it. If you really need it, I suggest a new question :-)